Transforming data with two groups for multiple regression analysis
I have a dataset includes 2 groups (HC, PT) and unfortunately, variables (8) are not normal. I'm trying to run a multiple regression to see if the relationship between the variable of interest ("X1"), after controlling for 7 other variables of no interest, and "Y" is different between groups.
Since my independent variables are not normal, I'm trying to transform the data using robust transformation, but would I need to transform within each group or pool all the data together?

First off, your independent variables do not need to be normally distributed. The typical assumption is that your residuals should be normally distributed. As a clear example of that, I explain this distinction and show in a simulated example here that having two non-normally distributed IVs/DVs, when specified correctly, still give you a normally distributed residual pattern, which is your ultimate goal (and sometimes even that doesn't really matter, see references in linked answer for discussion on this point).
This actually matters a lot less less for your IVs than your DV, as the predictors are "fixed and known" while our DV, as composed by our linear predictor, is random and has to be explicitly specified with a given distribution (e.g. Gaussian, binomial, etc.).
